# How accurate do I have to be in performing mitzvos to time?

Tags: tefilla, mitzvah, time, modern-times, hanetz-sunrise

We can now measure time more accurately than in the past (see [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4445/zmanim-accuracy-before-digital-clocks)). What are the implications? I do not ask about situations where the time is critical for a Torah law where obviously one should make sure that the time chosen is in the permitted zone.

But consider for example the time for Honetz Hachamah on a day when the sun is not visible. In earlier times, assume this time could have determined to within 5 minutes. My question is whether I have  to time my Amidah to the nearest minute on my clock or whether I can rely on the practice of earlier times and within 5 minutes either side would be still constitute tefillo at  Honetz Hachamah.

Comment: Why assume the practice in earlier times was to just get within 5 minutes of either side? Maybe on cloudy days they purposefully aimed late or something like that?

Comment: For Honetz Hachamah.which to choose, early or late?

Comment: Which is worse: shma after sunrise or amida before sunrise? Id think the latter is worse.